# Problem with missing Distutils folder after upgrading from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: django, ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm having an issue with virtualenv, and virtualenvwrapper after upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04.

I had a fully functional Django application in my Dev environment on Ubuntu 19.10, but since updating to 20.04 my virtualenv isn't working correct.

Specifically it says that:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/__init__.py
```

I've checked the path, and the distutils folder is missing, but I'm not sure how I go about fixing this.

There is a disutils folder in /usr/lib/python3.8, but when I copy that across to my python3.7 folder, I just get a different error.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239829/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-distutils-util

Comment: Thanks for trying to assist iklinac. I tried following the steps listed on that post, but that still didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this is to rebuild your virtualenv:

```
$ VENV=~/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv
$ rm -r $VENV
$ python3 -m venv $VENV
$ . $VENV/bin/activate
$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

This will remove your old virtualenv and create a new one based on the packages specified in `requirements.txt`.